# Jasmine test not firing 'click' event in test

Tags: javascript, jquery, testing, jasmine-jquery

I'm trying to create a test for Google Analytics but it looks like the event 'click' doesn't get fired.

Here's my code

```
trackEvent: function() {

        $eventID = $('[data-trigger="click"]');

        $eventID.on('click', function() {
            var element = $(this);
            var eventCategory = element.data('category') ? element.data('category') : '',
                eventAction = element.data('action') ? element.data('action') : '',
                eventLabel = element.data('label') ? element.data('label') : '',
                eventSocialNetwork = element.data('socialNetwork') ? element.data('socialNetwork') : '',
                eventSocialAction = element.data('socialAction') ? element.data('socialAction') : '',
                eventSocialTarget = element.data('socialTarget') ? element.data('socialTarget') : '';

            if(eventCategory !== '' && eventAction !== '' && eventLabel !== '') {

                ga('send', {
                    'hitType': 'event',
                    'eventCategory': eventCategory,
                    'eventAction': eventAction,
                    'eventLabel': eventLabel
                });
            }

            if(eventSocialNetwork !== '' && eventSocialAction !== '' && eventSocialTarget !== '') {

                ga('send', {
                    'hitType': 'social',
                    'socialNetwork': eventSocialNetwork,
                    'socialAction': eventSocialAction,
                    'socialTarget': eventSocialTarget
                });
            }

        });
    },
```

Here's my test

it('should fire social interaction event', function() {

```
        var theDiv = sandbox({
            'id': 'social-facebook',
            'data-trigger': 'click',
            'data-socialNetwork': 'facebook',
            'data-socialAction': 'share',
            'data-socialTarget': 'url'
        });


        $(document.body).append(theDiv);

        eventTracker.trackEvent();
        var event = jQuery.Event('click');
        event.target = jQuery('#social-facebook')[0];

        jQuery('#social-facebook').trigger('click');

        expect(window.ga).toHaveBeenCalledWith('send', {
            'hitType': 'social',
            'socialNetwork': 'facebook',
            'socialAction': 'share',
            'socialTarget': 'url'
        });

    });
```

Comment: If you are trying to check for immediate results, then make sure you are checking in Real-Time reports.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I'm trying to create a jasmine test.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I thought you meant the GA event.